# Tinc correct iptables configuration

Tags: iptables, vpn, firewall, tinc

I've been able to get tinc setup when I flush all my iptables, but after enabling iptables and a delay I get a "Destination Net Unknown".   I have three host (HOME10.0.3.2, MASTER 10.0.3.1, WEB 10.0.3.3) MASTER and WEB are in Digital ocean in the same data centre.

HOME <---> MASTER  <--->  WEB

I've tried multiple forwarding/masquerading/etc rules and don't understand what I'm missing.

When iptables are enabled (same rules on MASTER and WEB) I get the following results:

HOME $ ping 10.0.3.1  ==> Success
HOME $ ping 10.0.3.3  ==> Destination Net Unknown

MASTER $ ping 10.0.3.2  ==> Success
MASTER $ ping 10.0.3.3  ==> Destination Net Unknown

WEB $ ping 10.0.3.1  ==> Destination Net Unknown
WEB $ ping 10.0.3.2  ==> Destination Net Unknown

It's not just ICMP though, I get the same results for "nc -vz x.x.x.x 22"

I'd appreciate any help.

```
iptables -L -n -v

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 8 packets, 1120 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3306
    0     0 NRPE       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5666
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       x.x.x.x       0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       10.0.3.0/24          0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       10.0.3.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       10.0.3.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       x.x.x.x       0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:5666
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
  192 13741 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2222 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 limit: avg 25/min burst 100
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:123
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:2222 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:655 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    6  8976 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:655 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.0/16        ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 *       172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 NRPE       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:5666
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       10.0.3.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       10.0.3.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5666
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED
  140 44173 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:2222 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:123
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2222 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:655 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    6  8976 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:655 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain NRPE (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            x.x.x.x
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       x.x.x.x              0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0




iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 1831 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 1348 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 14 packets, 856 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 136 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Can you post iptables rules? Output of `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -n -v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I only had unidirectional ACCEPTs no bidirectional:

Failing:

```
# Allow Tinc VPN connections
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 655 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 655 -j ACCEPT
```

Working:

```
# Allow Tinc VPN connections
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 655 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 655 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 655 -j ACCEPT
```